# How to SetText of One Activity/Fragment from another one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, settext

I want to change the text of the Fragment_B from the Fragment_A. How can I do this?

Something like this.

Fragment_A

```
ola = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView12);
ola2 = (TextView) (FRAGMENT_B).findViewById(R.id.textView2);

AsyncTask(ola,ola2).execute //this should set text on Fragment_A and Fragment_B
```

Fragment A:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_second,container,false);


    ola = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    Asynctask(ola).execute

    return v;
}
```

Fragment B:

```
public class Fragmento_B extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    public TextView ola2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third,container,false);

        ola2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        Asynctask(ola2).execute
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start Fragment B with Arguments then fetch argument in Fragment B then fetch your value from argument then setText from your value.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem you are facing? Is it showing some sort of error or is it not changing the text as your or anything?

Comment: My code is working well but I'm calling AsyncTask.execute twice. I only want to run it once and update fragment_B textviews from the fragment_A. This way I dont need to run AsyncTask.execute in fragment_B.

Comment: I believe that you only have to pass the reference of ola2 to fragment A and just call the setText method on the ola2 view. I don't think an AsyncTask would be needed